# Does Google Licence Verification Library run on an Android Wear device?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-lvl

I have been looking into [Google LVL](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) to address stolen apps issues.

The API states the device need to "Run a system image on which the Google Play client application is preinstalled"
This cannot happend on a Wear device, but I am wondering if it can leverage the host phone instance of Google Client.

Has anyone faced this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't leverage the phone instance directly but a common approach at getting anything the phone can provide (network status etc) is to use the messaging api to send a custom message to request the information and get a message from the phone as a response.  You could easily add to your wearable listener service on the mobile side to call the licencing and then wrap up a response and send a message to the wearable.

Depending on what your app does I'd try to put this as part of an existing message from mobile to wear to save unnecessary chatter.

Comment: If I understand the workflow it is sub optimal. The mobile-app is only running when the user opens it, which could be never whereas the wear-app is always running.

Comment: I don't think licence checking is a priority on a wear app which is why it wasn't implemented and would just add bloat.  The general principle seems to be that anything requiring external/internet communication goes via the mobile app.  Just because your mobile app isn't running doesn't mean it cannot respond to wearable service requests.